# WSO2 APIM - SAML SSO - ACS URL

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

having WSO2AM 2.1.0 in distributed setup (KM, GW, TM deployed and scaled separately) we'd like to enable SAML SSO for application users with an external SAML IdP.

Main question is - **what is the SAML ACS url for the APIM as SP** in this setup?

By default (it's working) the ACS URL is  https://host:9443/commonauth , however as far I understood the client should have access only to the Gateway services (port 8243). On the port 8243 there are even all OAuth services exposed too.

So - do we need to expose a route / ports to 9443 (gateway to key manager)?

Thank you for any insight

Answer (score 0):

question is bit unclear. We can setup SSO for publisher and store applications only. There is no connection with the gateway when configuring this. see https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM2xx/Configuring+Identity+Server+as+IDP+for+SSO . Since API Publisher or store acts as the SP, We set ACS url for publisher as https://localhost:9443/publisher/jagg/jaggery_acs.jag and for store as https://localhost:9443/store/jagg/jaggery_acs.jag

Gateway is there to accept the API requests. so only 8243 and 8280 are needed to exposed to public. but gateway needs to talk to keymanager (to validate tokens) so there needs to be a connection between gateway and keymanager.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am aware the GW needs to talk to the KM. Question is - do the clients need to access KM directly? (well - now I see the default ACS included is url from KM)

Comment: No. You don't have to expose KM to clients. In gateway /token endpoint can be used to generate a token (internally it is routed to KM to generate tokens). So no need to expose KM at all to external

Comment: The issue I have is with federated SAML SSO (application starts the authorization using OAuth authorize service, user is authenticated using a SAML IdP). Then the ACS URL in the auth request is poiting to the KM ACS (which is https://km:9443/commonAuth), Question is - could be ACS defined on GW (and SAML auth request generated with GW hostname ACS)